# Showing that $\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{x^2}}}{x^2}\approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is an easy way to show that the following approximation is valid for large $t$?

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{k^2}}}{k^2}\approx \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}}$$

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-erfc-discrete-approximation.nb)

Comment: Is it not an equality? Plus what does your graph represents exactly (I suppose you have summed for $x <n$ but which $n$), otherwise, I would try to derivate... I have a request: could you change $x$ by $k$ or $n$ ?

Comment: Please, note that $\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)=1+O\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt t}\right)$ at $t\to\infty$. If you are not planning to keep exponentially small corrections, you can use the Euler-Macklaurin formula:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}e^{-\frac t{k^2}}\sim\int_1^\infty\frac1{k^2}e^{-\frac t{k^2}}dk=\int_0^1e^{-tx^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt t}+O\left(\frac{e^{-t}}t\right)$$
Switching from summation to integration we dropped exponentially small corrections. Therefore, with the same level of accuracy $\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)=1+O\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt t}\right)$

Answer (score 7):

We temporarily fix $t$ and consider the function $g(y) = ye^{-ty}$. Then

$$ g'(y) = (1 - ty)e^{-ty}, $$

hence the maximum of $ g(y) $ is achieved at $y = \frac{1}{t}$ with the maximum value of $g(\frac{1}{t}) = \frac{1}{et}$. This also shows that $g(y)$ is unimodal on $[0, \infty]$ (with the convention that $g(\infty) = 0$), and the same is true for $x \mapsto g(\frac{1}{x^2})$. Using this, it is not hard to show that

$$ \left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) - \int_{0}^{\infty} g\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, \mathrm{d}x \right| \leq 2\max_{y\in[0,\infty]}g(y) = \frac{2}{et}. $$

(As a hint, recall how the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Remark) is proved geometrically.) So,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t/k^2}}{k^2}
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t/x^2}}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x + \mathcal{O}(t^{-1}) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ty^2} \, \mathrm{d}x + \mathcal{O}(t^{-1}) \tag{$y = 1/x$} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{t}} + \mathcal{O}(t^{-1}).
\end{align*}

Now, using the fact that $\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{t}) = 1 + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}}\right)$ (see [DLMF 7.12.1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/7.12), for example), we can absorb the exponentially small error term to a larger term and obtain

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t/k^2}}{k^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{t})}{2\sqrt{t}} + \mathcal{O}(t^{-1}). $$

---

Alternatively, Euler–Maclaurin formula shows that, for any positive integer $p$,

\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t/k^2}}{k^2} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{t}} \right|
&\leq \frac{2\zeta (p)}{(2\pi)^{p}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\partial^p}{\partial x^p} \biggl( \frac{e^{-t/x^2}}{x^2} \biggr) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{2\zeta (p)}{(2\pi)^{p} t^{(p+1)/2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left| \frac{\partial^p}{\partial s^p} \biggl( \frac{e^{-1/s^2}}{s^2} \biggr) \right| \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}

This in fact shows that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t/k^2}}{k^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}(\sqrt{t})}{2\sqrt{t}} + \mathcal{O}(t^{-p}) $$

for any *fixed* $p$, hinting we actually have a better error bound.

Indeed, a numerical simulation suggests that the error term is of the form $\mathcal{O}(e^{-C\sqrt{t}})$ but I have no idea whether this is actually true or not.

Answer (score 3):

$$S_n=\sum _{k=1}^{n } \frac{e^{-\frac{t}{k^2}}}{k^2}$$

Using Euler-MacLaurin summation
$$S_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}}+e^{-t}\, P(t)-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ For this level of expansion
$$P(t)=\frac{808}{1155}-\frac{9397 t}{6930}+\frac{3461
   t^2}{693}-\frac{94579 t^3}{13860}+\frac{340553
   t^4}{83160}-$$ $$\frac{1021543 t^5}{831600}+\frac{5779
   t^6}{29700}-\frac{11
   t^7}{675}+\frac{t^8}{1485}-\frac{t^9}{93555}$$
Just a few numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
t & e^{-t}\, P(t) \\
 1 & +0.205872 \\
 2 & +0.016369 \\
 3 & +0.047570 \\
 4 & +0.004640 \\
 5 & -0.028220 \\
 6 & -0.016550 \\
 7 & +0.003639 \\
 8 & +0.010756 \\
 9 & +0.007377 \\
10 & +0.001856 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$