# Expressions for $f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } k^{-2} z^{k^{-2}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there another characterization for the following function?

$$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } k^{-2} z^{k^{-2}}$$

IE, can we write it as a transformation of the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) for instance?

Motivation: $f(\exp(t))$ gives the moment-generating function of $X$ sampled from $1,1/4,1/9,1/16,\ldots$ with relative sampling frequencies $1,1/4,1/9,1/16,\ldots$.

I'm approximating it with erf function (details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724413/showing-that-sum-x-1-infty-frace-fractx2x2-approx-frac)) and looking to get tighter bounds. ([Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-fitting-distr.nb))

Comment: Not sure if this would be useful at all, but you could write it as a Dirichlet series and potentially try looking for an Euler product and/or start looking at Dirichlet convolutions on the coefficients to try to find a different way to write it.

Comment: The following sum converges much faster though probably not the kind of characterization you're looking for.
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^m(z)}{m!} \zeta(2m+2)$$